# Replace nested variable in a file using Ansible

Tags: ansible

Let's say vars.yml contains the following.

```
john:
  foo: "bar"
jane:
  foo: "bar"
```

And I want to update the file so that only the john.foo nested variable contains Hello World.

```
john:
  foo: "Hello World"
jane:
  foo: "bar"
```

I suspect, but am not certain, that the playbook should have something like this. In this scenario, the shell module runs some command on the managed node that returns "Hello World", stored in the out variable. However, this fails to update the vars.yml file.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - shell: "some command here"
      register: out

    - replace:
        path: vars.yml
        regexp: "john: john | combine( {'foo': '{{ out.stdout }}'}, recursive=True)"
        replace: 'foo: "Hello World"'
```

Comment: Where do the data ``john; {'foo': 'bar'}`` come from? Are you really going to hard-code them? I'm asking because this piece of info will influence the solution. (Module "replace" modifies text.  Dictionaries in Ansible are immutable.)

Comment: Thanks again @VladimirBotka. I've updated my question showing that I am using the shell module with the register parameter to store "Hello World" in the out variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use *combine* to modify the dictionary include the variable and rewrite the file, e.g.

```yaml
    - command: echo Hello World
      register: out
    - include_vars:
        file: vars.yaml
        name: _dict
    - copy:
        content: |
          {{ _dict_update|to_nice_yaml }}
        dest: vars.yaml
      vars:
        _value: "{{ _dict.john|combine({'foo': out.stdout}) }}"
        _dict_update: "{{ _dict|combine({'john': _value}) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat vars.yaml 
jane:
    foo: bar
john:
    foo: Hello World
```

The filter *to_nice_yaml* doesn't quote the strings.

Comment: Amazing @VladimirBotka. This works flawlessly. You are an absolute whiz with Ansible.